# infinite loop in applescript stops logout

Tags: macos, applescript, infinite-loop, repeat

So I am writing a basic applescript to end a very annoying program that randomly  opens and interrupts me while Im working. The program needs to stay but i don't want to see it. I want my script to open automatically when the computer restarts (I did this in settings). I want to test to make sure it works but upon saving it as an application I cannot logout or shutdown or restart without manually force quitting. I assume this is because of the repeat loop but i don't know how to fix this. Ive tried everything i could think of. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you

```
on appIsRunning(appName)
    tell application "System Events" to (name of processes) contains appName
end appIsRunning

repeat

if appIsRunning("LiveUpdate") then
    tell application "LiveUpdate"
        quit
    end tell



end repeat
```

Comment: If there's a plist for LiveUpdate in `{~,}/Library/Launch{Daemons,Agents}`, try deleting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you have the proper approach either. However, if you want to do what you are trying to do then you want to create a stay-open application. You do that by saving the applescript as an application and checking the "stay open after run handler" checkbox. Here's how you write the code for that...

```
on idle
    if appIsRunning("LiveUpdate") then tell application "LiveUpdate" to quit
    return 10
end idle

on appIsRunning(appName)
    tell application "System Events" to (name of processes) contains appName
end appIsRunning
```

Notice the "on idle" handler. That is the handler that is repeatedly run while the application stays open. Notice that I have placed "return 10" at the end of that handler. That determines how often the idle handler runs, in this case every 10 seconds. You can change that to what you want.

The advantage of this method is that you can quit this stay-open application. You won't get stuck in a repeat loop that you can't quit.

You mention that you do not want to see this application while it is running. To make that happen you will have to modify the info.plist file inside the application bundle (right-click on the application and show package contents). You have to add the "LSUIElement" key to the plist and give it a value of true. Then you won't see the application in the Dock while it's running.

Because you can't see it running you will need some way to quit the application. You can do that either using another applescript...

```
tell application "My Stay Open Application" to quit.
```

Or you can open activity monitor and quit it from there. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

```
on idle
if application "LiveUpdate" is running then tell application "LiveUpdate" to quit
return 10
end idle
```